# Adding content of file 1 to file 2 in C

Tags: c

I am trying to add the content of a first file (a.txt) in the end of a second file (b.txt)... but I am not sure how to do this. I have the following code.

```
        int i = 0;
        char delims[] = " \n";
        char *result = NULL;
        char * results[10];
        result = strtok( cmdStr, delims );
        while( result != NULL ) {
            results[i] = result;
            i++;
            result = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }

        // results[1] shows a.txt
        // results[2] shows b.txt

        FILE *fp;
        char ch;

        if((fp = fopen(results[1],"r")) == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        } else {
            ...
            // add the content of results[1] in the end of results[2]
            ...
        }
        fclose(fp);
```

Results[1] is the name of the file a.txt.
Results[2] is the name of the file b.txt.

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to read file? how to write to it in general?

Comment: The broad outline is:  Open both files (b.txt for WRITING, a.txt for READING).  Read from a.txt; Write to b.txt; repeat until done.

Which steps are you having problems with?

Comment: I know it is used fputs(filename, content);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `results[2]` in append mode:

```
FILE *fp2;

fp2 = fopen(results[2], "a");  // a is for append
```

Then you can just loop through the first file and dump to the second one.. something like:

```
char line[100] = {0};
while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)
  fputs(line, fp2);
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's a full compiling program that takes the contents of "test.txt" and appends it to "test2.txt":

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    char line[100] = {0};
    char * results[2] = {"test.txt", "test2.txt"};
    fp = fopen(results[0], "r");
    fp2 = fopen(results[1], "a");  // a is for append

    while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)
       fputs(line, fp2);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've inserted that in the final else statement... but it is not doing anything.

Comment: @user1893187 - then something else is wrong (see edit for a working version of the code). Did you check that your `results[1]` and `results[2]` are really the "a.txt" and "b.txt" as you expect? (are you sure it's not `results[0]` and `results[1]`?) Did you check that the file opened for appending was opened successfully? Did you check that there is something in your file to read out? Did you try a debugger?

Comment: Thanks. Apparently it was because I had not the fclose. After I inserted that it worked fine. Thanks alot :)